# Picture of a decapitated Egyptian robot's head with wires coming out of its neck

Tags: robots, character-identification, art

Sometime ago I met a girl who had the most stunning tattoo of a decapitated robot's head on her arm.  It may have been an Egyptian robot's head, but it was simply stunning.  I recall there were wires and bits of metal coming out of its neck.

The girl did say it was quite a famous and well-known sci-fi art picture but I am unable to find a copy of it anywhere.

Does this ring any bells with anyone at all?

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Would it be possible to find a picture at all of this?  That would be of tremendous help.  Any other details would also be useful.  Thanks

Comment: A robot head, like the one Kai is holding in [this picture](http://tinyurl.com/puqjcwy)?

Comment: Thanks but no , the picture (from memory) was very detailed , I recall there were wires and bits of metal coming out of its neck and I think it was some sort of Egyptian robot head .

Comment: Could be something based on H R Giger's work. Can't search for specific examples right now, so not posting as an answer.

Comment: This is going to be a difficult one to find. Perhaps you could add information about what works of SF you're familiar with, so we know what _isn't_ it.

Comment: The nationality of your "Girl With the Robot Tatoo" might help, too.

Comment: Ohh - that would make a great name for a mystery novel!

Comment: When you met the girl, you didn't exchange phone numbers or email addresses or anything? No way to get in touch with her?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean with Egyptian robot head. AFAIK the Egypts didn't have robots.

Comment: @MrLister No [Egyptian robots](https://www.facebook.com/egyptian.robot)?

Comment: Girl with tattoo was Australian , i didn't get her number as i was married at the time . I will try to get more info to refine the search .

Comment: What about Johnny Sokko and his flying robot? I seem to recall that the robot had an Egyption looking head.

Comment: Sorry but no ....

Comment: @Dr W - if you can, could you sketch out the rough shape  or outline from memory and show which way the head is facing? Were there any colours or skin tones or all metallic or plastic?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I did want to clarify: she said the robot was from a famous piece of *science fiction artwork*? Not just a famous work of science fiction? That will narrow down the options considerably -- any answer that just shows a screen-shot is likely wrong.

Comment: Sometime ago= 30 years? 95% chance if you had a tattoo of an Egyptian cyborg robot head in 1985, it was of Eddie.

Comment: I had a book a couple of years ago with a decapitated robots head on the cover. Head On by John Scalzi - I no longer have it but I'm fairly sure it had wires hanging out

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, the most famous decapitated robot (technically, android) head in science fiction is that of **Data** from ***Star Trek: The Next Generation***:

[image: Close up of the prop for Data's head, a pale human android head with a metal socket on the bottom and a couple of wires]

In the original question, you wrote, *"The girl did say it was quite famous and well-known..."* and in the in the comments you wrote, *"...the picture (from memory) was very detailed, I recall there were wires and bits of metal coming out of its neck..."*  Data fits that bill on both counts.

As seen in the episode ["Time's Arrow"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_(episode)):

[image: The head, as above, on a covered surface as shown in the show]

Comment: @DrW : If this is not the droid you're looking for, let me know.

Comment: The gold eyes and metallic skin fit the "Egyptian" appearance, to me. I hope this is it.

Answer (score 4):

Egyptian robot head from a famous StF work? It has to be *Stargate*. Check out the guard helmets:

[image: stargate guard helmet view from the front left, profile, rear and front showing its Anubis style design with the cat/dog like shaped head and long pointed ears]

Comment: What's StF? Did you mean SF for sci-fi?

Comment: Scientifiction.

Comment: But I've only ever seen it written stf, it's scientifiction not ScientiFiction, so StF looks weird.

Answer (score 4):

Heavy metal band, *Iron Maiden's* legendary, [**Eddie the Head**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_the_Head). Eddie's head is [often disembodied](https://wall.alphacoders.com/by_sub_category.php?id=173498&name=Iron+Maiden+Wallpapers) and a lot of their cover art has Egyptian stuff on them. In custom artwork such as a tattoo, I'd expect all sorts of *wires and bits of metal coming out of his neck*, as is the norm for depictions of him in fan art.

> Eddie assumes a different guise relating to the themes of individual albums and their corresponding world tours, and has appeared as a cyborg, an Egyptian mummy and a lobotomised mental patient amongst others. –Wiki

[image: Close up of a tattoo of Eddie with wraps around his skull face and his teeth bared chewing on a metal chain] [image: Somewhere Back in Time cover showing a futuristic Eddie blasting through a pyramid with a cyborg fitment on his head and a blaster in one hand, at the front sits an Egyptian statue styled like Eddie]

Answer (score 3):

## **Cybermen from *Doctor Who***

A well-known robot that has often been seen with a severed head could be the Cybermen from *Doctor Who*. Below are some examples:

A *Classic Doctor Who* Cyberman-head from "Death in Heaven":

[image: A Cyberman-head on paving stones outside, it has been torn off of the body and the top right of its head has been caved in revealing wiring and circuitry underneath]

A *Classic Doctor Who* Cyberman-head from "Dalek":

[image: Close up of a Cyberman-head in a glass display case with wires coming out of the bottom of it]

Handles, the Cyber-head from "The Time of The Doctor":

[image: The Doctor and Clara look across at each other in front of a severed Cyberman-head that is mounted on an instrument in the TARDIS, wires stick out from the neck and it is cracked in various places revealing a blue light just above the left eye]

The Cyberman-head from "The Pandorica Opens":

[image: A Cyberman-head on the floor of a dark area with long cables sticking out the bottom of its neck]

Answer (score 3):

## Battle Droids from *Star Wars I-III*

The Battle Droids, first seen in *The Phantom Menace*, look Egyptian with their long necks, thin heads, and markings. The back of the head resembles a pharaoh's turban. Battle droid heads are often severed during combat, especially when facing the Jedi.

- Compare a Battle droid with Anubis:

  [image: Battle droid on the left, thin humanoid robot with a backpack on and antenna coming out of it holding a blaster, it has a long thin neck and a ant eater shaped narrow head. An Anubis on the right: humanoid, slightly more muscular with an Egyptian headrests on and cat-like face in a similar style to the battle droid with two large pointy ears]
- Severed Battle Droid head with wires sticking out:

  [image: A close up on a battle droids severed head with a whole bunch of wires sticking up out of the bottom of the neck]
- Battle Droid head close up (the *eyes* especially look Egyptian to me):

  [image: A head on and side view close up on the head with no neck, the eyes are black ovals with an strip missing out of the middle to give two semi-circles together]

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's IMHO nothing that looks Egyptian here, but Ash's head in *Alien* definitely has those wires you're mentioning, and that's for sure, a decapitated robot's head.

[image: Ash's head covered in a white slime-like substance in the floor with wires going over to his decapitated body lying next to him]